# Add values in Varray using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a varray string:

```
string[] imgList = new[] { };
```

And I retrieve the list of files:

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles("*.jpg");
```

I want to add in my varray using LINQ the result. Some like this:

```
imgList = files.Where(x => x.FullName).ToList();
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You've used the term "varray" twice - what do you mean by it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `Where` to `Select`, and `ToList()` to `ToArray()` in your query.

```
imgList = files.Select(x => x.FullName).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles("*.jpg");

string[] imgList = files.Select(p => p.Name).ToArray();

// or, without LINQ, probably a little faster:

string[] imgList = Array.ConvertAll(files, p => p.Name);
```

Note that in both cases you don't need to create the array beforehand, because a new array is returned by the `Array.Convert`/`.ToArray()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have some error in your code.

First you have an incorrect string array declaration,
second you are trying convert `.ToList()` to string array. So try something like this

```
 string[] imgList = new string[] { };
 DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
 FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles("*.jpg");

 imgList = files.Where(x => x.FullName == "myCondition").Select(x => x.FullName).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a method that returns an array, as well the method you're using which returns a `List<T>`, so try:

```
imgList = files.Select(x => x.FullName).ToArray();
```